# SharePoint user control deployment issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, sharepoint-2007

I am using SharePoint 2007 Enterprise with Windows Server 2008. I am using VSTS 2008 + C# + .Net 3.5. I am new to SharePoint user control development and deployment. I am learning from,

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/sharepoint/PageFooter.aspx

But confused about the following deployment steps, my question is in what files do I need to modify to insert the following code segments?

Register your control:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="Flygare" 
    TagName="PageFooter" src="~/_controltemplates/PageFooter.ascx" %>
```

Insert your control:

```
<Flygare:PageFooter id="PageFoot" runat="server" enableviewstate="true">
</Flygare:PageFooter>
```

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be a layout file...with a .ASPX extension

See [Create a new Page Layout in SharePoint 2007 feature based](http://weblogs.asp.net/jimjackson/archive/2007/11/05/create-a-new-page-layout-in-sharepoint-2007-feature-based.aspx)

Or you could go to the [12 hive](http://msmvps.com/blogs/laflour/archive/2009/04/14/sharepoint-tip-31-do-you-know-the-12-hive-folder-structure-details.aspx) (C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\12) and find the ([Template\LAYOUTS](http://www.pointsharepoint.com/2008/08/exploring-12-hive-template.html)) folder. Open a layout file that is being used for a site and then add those tags.

Comment: The last link can not be opened.

http://www.pointsharepoint.com/2008/08/exploring-12-hive-template.html

Comment: Your first document seems cool. So the correct method to deploy a customized function is -- I should developed a user control, then deploy it as a MOSS 2007 feature? If so, could you recommend a step-by-step guide from user control development to feature deploy (the document you recommended as the first link seems only contain how to deploy a feature)?

Comment: Cool, AboutDev! Question answered!